# WordPress custom authentication implementation

Tags: plugin-development, authentication

I created a plugin to allow my website to have its own login functionality.

My project has a new requirement which is to log in to the user with my own authentication method and not the one provided by WP.

Which actions and filters do I need to use so I can create my own authentication method? And once my authentication method is successful how can I log in the user to the WP site? I don't want to use a plugin.

Would someone shed some light or point me to a guide that shows me how to achieve it.

Currently I only know that my own authentication method should be implemented in:

`add_action('wp_authenticate_user', 'custom_authentication', 10, 2);`

Comment: What is your authentication mechanism? Is it a directory i.e. another list of users and passwords that you just want to get WordPress to check the password entered against, or an entirely separate site, or something else?

Comment: When you say a custom authentication method can you be more specific? E.g. you could roll a pretty simple ( insecure ) solution, but that same approach would not work for a protocol such as SAML that relies on redirecting the user. Also can you explain why you don't want to just use a plugin that already does it?

Comment: Also highly relevant: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate_user/

Comment: Ok. My authentication mechanism is to check the username and password on a different database and once the user is identified I need to log in the user in the WP site. I don't want to use a plugin because I want to have the control on my own code.

Comment: Then yes, you probably want wp_authenticate_user and (I'd guess) a pluggable override of wp_check_password so that you can use wp_authenticate_username_password and wp_authenticate_email_password, or simply write your own authenticate_user hook and drop those two. Either way that's the code you need to look at.

Comment: @Rup thank you so much. Do you have any code sample please.

Comment: No, sorry. Your best bet to find a code sample is to look at a plugin that does something similar. But you can probably just figure it out from the core WordPress code too. Or [here's an old probably-relevant question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/268665/3276) too.

Comment: @Rup I am in the same boat as she/he was: "I’ve stumbled upon overriding the wp_authenticate via a custom plugin, which I’ve already set up but I’m stumped as to what and HOW to even do this". Hopefully this helps. Thanks

Comment: @Rup answers go in answers, comments are for clarifying questions

Comment: Also, if this other database is a WordPress database, then the optimal solution is probably WP Multisite, which would let you share users across numerous sites in the same install

Comment: @Rup thank you Rup. You have pointed me in the right direction of what I wanted to do. Once I get this working I will add an answer to my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This question [Set up WP Authentication from External API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268665/set-up-wp-authentication-from-external-api) has a link to a blog. That put me in the right direction and shed some light on my work (Thanks @Rup).

```php
class CustomLogin
{
    /**
     * Initializes the plugin.
     *
     * To keep the initialization fast, only add filter and action hooks in the constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter('authenticate', array($this, 'my_custom_authentication'), 10, 3);
        remove_action('authenticate', array($this, 'wp_authenticate_username_password'), 20);
        remove_action('authenticate', array($this, 'wp_authenticate_email_password'), 20);
        add_action('authenticate', array($this, 'new_wp_authenticate_email_password'), 20, 3);
    }

    public function my_custom_authentication($user, $userName, $password)
    {
        $authenticationResponse = $this->custom_authentication($userName, $password);
        if (isset($authResponse['Auth_Error']) && !empty($authResponse['Auth_Error']))
            return 0;
        $user = get_user_by('email', $authenticationResponse['Auth_Email']);
        if (!empty($user))
            return $user;
        else
            return 0;
        // Add WP_Error message where ever is convinient for you
    }

    public function new_wp_authenticate_email_password($user, $userName, $password)
    {
        if ($user instanceof WP_User) {
            return $user;
        }
        // Validations and WP_Error message
    }
}
```

I used a plugin and the code above first validates a user on the external service. If the user is found on the external service and then on WordPress I return the user which logs the user in, if not, I return an error message.

The numbers you see in the constructor are priorities which determine the moment that the action or filter will be triggered.

```php
add_filter('authenticate', array($this, 'my_custom_authentication'), 10, 3);
```

If you want to know more about those priorities numbers please have a read to this: https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-login-hooks/

Thanks :)