# Single Sign On in Wordpress

Tags: single-sign-on

I am provided with a api for single sign on service. They ask me to integrate it in the wordpress frontend for user login.

How can I use something that have functionality like SocialiteProvider of Laravel in Wordpress?
How can I integrate a custom socialite providers like this?

Comment: what do you mean by socialite is that a service? SSO has many different technologies so you'll need to be specific, e.g. OAuth2/SAML/etc, and there are plugins that implement those if you don't want to implement it from scratch. Importantly though, what's the question? Are you asking for recommendations? If so the question is offtopic and should be asked on the software recs stack

Comment: socialite like socialiteprovider, a library used in laravel. I have my own api using oauth2. It was implemented as sso in the laravel app using SocialiteProvider library, which they configured as a custom provider. In wordpress, the plugin does not offer the same or close to the laravel library. I'm asking if there is a way to implement functionalities that are close to laravel library? Currently, I found Hybridauth, a standalone library offer similar functionality, but I haven't figure out how can I create a custom provider. @tom-j-nowell. Do you understand what am I asking? Can you help?

Comment: there are filters that can be used to control setting up sessions and perform redirects, calls in to libraries, etc, and there are multiple OAuth2 implementations out there that can be used as references, some of which use libraries such as those from the PHP league. I don't believe though that you'll find a nice neat go to library that everybody recommends and uses though, and you might be doing yourself a disservice by constraining your search to just SocialiteProvider equivalents, WP custom authentication would yield more interesting results

Comment: try looking at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268665/set-up-wp-authentication-from-external-api for example

Comment: Thank you very much.